# Laravel casting JSON to array?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to convert the a JSON field to array. For example the model is like this:

```
protected $casts = [
    'content' => 'array'
];
```

While in insert the content inside, I do it like this:

```
'content'=> json_encode([
                'description' => $faker->paragraph(3),
                'about' => $faker->paragraph(2),
                'info' => $faker->paragraph(2),
                'updated' => $faker->dateTimeBetween('-1 years', 'now')
]),
```

But while getting the data it prints a string, nothing else.

The migration in this part looks like this:

```
$campaign->json('content');
```

Sample of the output:

```
"content": "{\"description\":\"Ut quas quo odio illo. Voluptates quia fuga itaque sint. Velit sapiente fugit ea ut ducimus sint tempora eligendi. Ea et molestiae consequuntur quibusdam soluta voluptatem.\",\"about\":\"Aut voluptates et iste ut perspiciatis. Esse sunt ullam inventore sit doloremque et quisquam.\",\"info\":\"Corrupti et facere exercitationem consequatur aspernatur quo saepe. Omnis et tempore enim ut. Quia magnam quia enim et eos enim.\",\"updated\":{\"date\":\"2015-11-22 08:25:13.000000\",\"timezone_type\":3,\"timezone\":\"UTC\"}}",
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: RTM: [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). _Also, you already have an array when you set `'key' => 'value'`. What are you trying to achieve? xD_

Comment: I am casting the elements from the model so when the controllers returns JSON it does looks like a JSON object and not a string. That way is easy to manipulate and use :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you define `array` cast you don't need to do any `json_encode` or `json_decode`. When you want to insert, simple you need to do:

```
'content'=> [
    'description' => $faker->paragraph(3),
    'about' => $faker->paragraph(2),
    'info' => $faker->paragraph(2),
    'updated' => $faker->dateTimeBetween('-1 years', 'now')
],
```

Laravel will do the rest

And when you want to get `content` field data, you simple need to use:

```
$campaign->content;
```

and you will have here array, so if you want to display description, you simple need to do:

```
echo $campaign->content['description'];
```

Comment: thanks that was it.. I totally got lost there, since I was placing an array before like in laravel 4, but it throw an error while seeding, but looks like I needed to read the error better... thanks mate :)

Answer (score 18):

If you want your mind blown...

```
// automatically handles json_encode, json_decode to php object
protected $casts = [
    'db_json_column' => 'object'
];

$model->db_json_column = $array; // persisted as json
$object = $model->db_json_column; // retrieved as object
```

or,

```
// automatically handles json_encode, json_decode to php array
protected $casts = [
    'db_json_column' => 'array'
];

$model->db_json_column = $array; // persisted as json
$array = $model->db_json_column; // retrieved as array
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `json_decode` with `option array true`

```
json_decode($casts['content'], true));
```

Comment: How would you implement that when the data is being fetch via relationships and `$data->content;` to fetch that part of the model?

Comment: You can try $data->toArray()